# UISplitViewController on iPad: stopping Master view to appear when touching on detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I created a **Master/DetailView** project on iOS for iPad. I set portrait mode only and I got my app running. In the detail view I added a UITableView with some customised cells (iOS settings style).

Fig. below: iOS settings menu. *In my case when touching the margins of the UISlider in the brightness group I would some times summon the master view (which in my project I would like to disappear - differently from the settings menu of iOS).*

[image]

However I got a little problem.. sometimes when I touch the margins of the cell the master view will appear and the action that I was doing in the cell gets void. Any idea on how I can **stop the master view to be summoned by the detail view when the user touches the borders of the detail viewstrong text**?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting presentsWithGesture to false for your UISplitViewController.